# css dropdown in a dialog extended outside the dialog

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dialog

I have a dropdown in a dialog and I would like to make it overflowing the dialog and at the time scrolling with inside the dialog.

Without JavaScript would be perfect.

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/teguzoxi/1/edit

Comment: Why someone asked to close this question?

Comment: **[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

You will need javaScript to toggle the visibility.

The scrolling and the max size of the contents can be done with css.

http://jsbin.com/teguzoxi/3/edit?html,css,js,output

```
  <style>
  ul {
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  </style>

  <button>Toggle Options</button>
  <ul>
     <li>red</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>pink</li>
    <li>purple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
  </ul> 

  <script>
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('ul').toggle();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I need to put some html elements inside the dropdown so a `<select>` as a dropdown is not what I search.